# Android System.loadLibrary crashing

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface, android-studio-import

I'm trying to include a `c file`, `ImageProc` into my java file to use it's functions.

I got the code from a `MjpegInputStream file` (where everything is supposed to work, but of course its never that easy)

Here is the code that crashes (somehow the catch isn't catching it)

```
static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("ImageProc");
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

The `makefile` is:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := ImageProc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ImageProc.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -ljnigraphics
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := prebuilt-libjpeg
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES       := external/include jni/external/include
```

So to my understanding I should just be able to use `ImageProc`.

I know it went through and compiled the `c file` because at first it couldn't find the h file references (fixed now).

One other thing i'm not sure about is that I call the function `pixeltobmp` which in the c file is defined as `Java_com_camera_simplemjpeg_MjpegInputStream_pixeltobmp` which strikes me as odd. I tried changing the name of the method to include the package i'm using rather than the one I copied it from, but that didn't fix anything.

Any help is appreciated.

Additional info: I'm using gradle build 2.10

Answer (score 1):

```
 1. Compile your library
 2. Check if you have the .so compiled library(this is important!)
 3. In your gradle file add this:

      android {  
        compileSdkVersion 23
            buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

            defaultConfig {
                minSdkVersion 18
                    targetSdkVersion 23
                    versionCode 1
                    versionName "1.0"
                }

                sourceSets.main {
                    jni.srcDirs = []
                    File configFile = file('pathToYourLibsFolder')
                    jniLibs.srcDir configFile.absolutePath
                }
```

Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
           ...
        }
        buildTypes {
            ...
        }
        ndk {
            moduleName "ImageProc"
            // stl "stlport_static"
            // ldLibs "log"
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That doesn't work with the gradle build i'm using, 2.10. I've tried with other ones that worked and it didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative option, the code that you're using can be easily modified to remove the dependency on OpenCV (or it can now 2 years after you asked the question).

[MjpegInputStream.java](https://bitbucket.org/neuralassembly/simplemjpegview/src/6a5cf5bd8f648f05cff6f4dffdcadb422f99fad5/app/src/main/java/com/camera/simplemjpeg/MjpegInputStream.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) has two relevant methods, `readMjpegFrame()` and `readMjpegFrame(Bitmap bmp)`.

Only the later relies on OpenCV and therefore the native library dependency. If you modify the code to remove this method, and then remove:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("ImageProc");
}

public native int pixeltobmp(byte[] jp, int l, Bitmap bmp);

public native void freeCameraMemory();
```

You will no longer have this problem and can still use `readMjpegFrame()` to get the content you want.

Whether this is less performant, I'm not certain, but it's working fine in my use case.